# Preventing implicit call to base constructor within copy constructor

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

I want to prevent the call of the default constructor, so I can force the user to use a specialized constructor. To do that I simply delete the default constructor.

An issue arises when I want to create a copy constructor for a derived class. It seems that the derived class' copy constructor makes an implicit call to the parents default constructor (which is deleted). The compiler does not like this!

Is there any way around this implicit call?

```
#include <iostream>

class Base
{
public:
    Base() = delete;

    Base(int x)
    : _x(x)
    {
        std::cout << "Base's constructor" << std::endl;
    }

    Base(const Base &other)
    {
        std::cout << "Base's copy constructor" << std::endl;
        this->_x = other._x;
    }

protected:
    int _x;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    Derived() = delete;

    Derived(int x, int y)
    : Base(x),  _y(y)
    {
        std::cout << "Derived's constructor" << std::endl;
    }

    Derived(const Derived &other)
    {
        // Implict call to Base(), which is deleted, and compilation fails.
        std::cout << "Derived's copy constructor" << std::endl;
        this->_x = other._x;
        this->_y = other._y;
    }

protected:
    int _y;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Derived d(10,10);
    Derived d2(d);
}
```

Comment: Call the base copy-constructor explicitly?

Comment: Of course. I don't know why I didn't think of that.
Thanks!

Comment: You actually thought too much as compiler generated copy ctor would work just fine. And you do not need to explicitly delete default ctor, as it would be suppressed anyway.

Comment: I was trying to provide a minimal example. My actual use case is a bit more complicated. Although, that is a good suggestion. I wasn't aware that the default constructor was suppressed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that since all constructors initialize all of their members before the enter the body of the constructor

```
Derived(const Derived &other)
{
    // Implict call to Base(), which is deleted, and compilation fails.
    std::cout << "Derived's copy constructor" << std::endl;
    this->_x = other._x;
    this->_y = other._y;
}
```

is actually

```
Derived(const Derived &other) : Base(), _y()
{
    // Implict call to Base(), which is deleted, and compilation fails.
    std::cout << "Derived's copy constructor" << std::endl;
    this->_x = other._x;
    this->_y = other._y;
}
```

Where `Base()` calls the base class default constructor.

What you need to do is leverage the member initializer list to call the base class copy constructor instead of the default constructor.  To do that you use

```
Derived(const Derived &other) : Base(other), _y(other._y)
{
    // Implict call to Base(), which is deleted, and compilation fails.
    std::cout << "Derived's copy constructor" << std::endl;
    // this->_x = other._x; no longer needed as Base(other) takes care of _x
    // this->_y = other._y; no longer needed as _y(other._y) takes care of _y
}
```

---

You should also update `Base`'s copy constructor to

```
Base(const Base &other) : _x(other._x)
{
    std::cout << "Base's copy constructor" << std::endl;
}
```

---

You should also note that there you can get away without defining any of these copy constructors.  Since you haven't defined a destructor the compiler will automatically generate copy constructors for both classes and those default copy constructors will just work.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `=delete` to prevent calling the default constructor. You could use the previous technique which was to declare it `private`. Of course, in this case, because you want it to be accessible to derived classes, you would make it `protected` instead.

But you can also explicitly construct the needed base class:

```
Derived(const Derived &other)
    : Base(other._x)
    , _y(other._y)
{
    std::cout << "Derived's copy constructor" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: "You could use the previous technique which was to declare it private" it would not make any difference here

Comment: I doubt it is any better. OP does not want to access default ctor from derived class, it just happened because he does not understand how it works. And doing `delete` is exactly proper way here.